# How can I animate a group of objects in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Whenever I group two rectangles together the animation stops working, but it works fine with each rectangle separately. How can I fix this?

```
<svg width="800" height="600" style="background-color:black">

<g id="rects">
<rect x="50" y="400" width="50"
height="20" fill="gold" />
<rect x="50" y="470" width="50"
height="20" fill="gold" />
</g>

<animate xlink:href="#rects"
attributeName="fill" dur="4s"
repeatCount="indefinite"
values="gold; gold; ivory; gold"
keyTimes="0; 0.7; 0.8; 1" />

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fill on the rect elements has a greater [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the fill on the g element. Remove the rect elements fill to fix.

```html
<svg width="800" height="600" style="background-color:black">

<g id="rects">
<rect x="50" y="400" width="50"
height="20" />
<rect x="50" y="470" width="50"
height="20" />
</g>

<animate xlink:href="#rects"
attributeName="fill" dur="4s"
repeatCount="indefinite"
values="gold; gold; ivory; gold"
keyTimes="0; 0.7; 0.8; 1" />

</svg>
```